# msqld: Can't change dir (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed mysql for Mac 10.14 using the .dmg file at the top here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/, and ran through the installer. My system os is Mac 10.13.6, but there is a note that says this should work.

At `/usr/local/` there's both a `mysql` folder and a `mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64` folder.

When I run `mysqld` I get the following error:

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64/data/' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
ts 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 9863
ts 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64/data/Monicas-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
ts 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
ts 0 [ERROR] [MY-010172] [Server] failed to set datadir to /usr/local/mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64/data/
ts 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
ts 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

`ts` is the UTC timestamp.

Is the problem that the command `mysqld` comes from `/usr/local/mysql/` and the directory to write to `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.13...../data/`? Does my user on my work computer not have the correct permissions to write to these directories?

I've tried `sudo`:

```
 Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
```

Comment: Not an exact solution to your problem, but docker immensely helps in elevating these problems. You don't need install on the actual system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart computer.

If that doesn't work:

- If you are in a virtualenv try installing required python-to-mysql libraries globally, that also helped.
- The final thing to try is

  `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib/:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}"`